Face orientation viewport overlay doesn't show up
Good day!
I can't see anything when ticking the face orientation option...
No X-Ray mode, Theme colors are okay and I turn off all 3rd party addons and it doesn't fix it either.
When loading factory preferences, It fixs it but I lose all my custom Keymaps so I wouldn't want to do that.
Are there any related options that I'm missing?


Hi. You turned off all 3rd party addons. Did you close Blender and then turn them back on one at a time and check what happens after turning on each addon? It is important that you close Blender after deactivating your addons. You mention that loading factory settings fixes it. That is usually a sign that a 3rd party addon is causing the problem.

Apparently, The alpha values of Face Orientation Front/Back color in themes were set to 0 somehow. Setting them to 1 got both colors back to normal! I wasn't aware of that I should restart Blender after deactivating addons... Learnt a new thing! Appareciate your reply!

If this is a fix, could either one of you post it as an answer, please? ... or, (trpid,) delete, or drop us a note here, saying you don't mind closing your post. Thanks.

@RobinBetts I will post an answer based on the comment if nothing more is heard from trpld. What would be a reasonable amount of time to wait?

Thanks @curious_1 .. I guess, if convenient,  leave it a day for trpid to self-answer and earn a bit of rep, just to be nice to a beginner? But no blame for going right ahead :)

Sorry guys, new to here. Is there anything further to do? Have no idea how this works haha. So I post a question and should delete the post when it's fixed or something??? How do I post this as an answer? I don't see any buttons like Pick this comment as an answer or like Solved! or something

TL;DR It can be confusing for newbies. I suggest scroll to the bottom of the page. In that blue "footer" area in the left hand column labeled "Blender" click on Help. Another suggestion is that when you have time, to look at some of the topics in that Help section and look at the Tour section. It will give you a better idea of how the site works. For now, here is the link about answering your own question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer   Continued...

To input your answer scroll down below the comment section to where it says "Your Answer". Click inside the box and write your answer. In what I will call the header of the Answer box, on the right side is a blue question mark for help with formatting it. It looks like the first sentence of your first comment will do for the answer. I recommend that if you could add some details, like an image showing where these changed theme settings are located, it would improve your answer considerably. Also note that after 48 hours you can accept your self-answered question.

Thanks for your detailed info! It helps a lot.

If you don't see anything when ticking Face Orientation in the Viewport Overlays options, Check

X-Ray mode should be off
Under Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Face Orientation Back/Front check Alpha values of both colours shouldn't be 0

